# TSQL get data regardless of Null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is getting information from my employee table and returning the data.

There are 3 columns that are used:

```
 B.[SiloDesc] + ' (' + B.[TitleDesc] + ') ' + B.[SkillSetDesc] as SkillSetDesc,
```

My issue is, if one of those happens to be null, it wont display any of the data. What is the best way to have it include the data regardless of if one of those fields are null.

Comment: You need to add COALESCE for each NULLable column, e.g. COALESCE(B.[SiloDesc],'')

Comment: Did you find [either](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22844223/621962) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22844157/621962) helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`coalesce()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [`isnull()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) for each individual column... or you could simply use...

> `CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] )`
>
> > Takes a variable number of string arguments and concatenates them into a single string. It requires a minimum of two input values; otherwise, an error is raised. All arguments are implicitly converted to string types and then concatenated. **Null values are implicitly converted to an empty string.**

**A.:** Remove the parentheses when `TitleDesc` is `null`:

```
select concat(B.[SiloDesc], ' (' + B.[TitleDesc] + ')', ' ' + B.[SkillSetDesc])
```

<sub>Because of the way `null` is treated in sql, the expression `' (' + null + ')'` results in `null` which `concat()` will treat as an empty string... which is kind of nice as it effectively removes the parentheses if the value is `null`.</sub>

**B.:** Keep the parentheses regardless:

```
select concat(B.[SiloDesc], ' (', B.[TitleDesc], ') ', B.[SkillSetDesc])
```

Samples:

```
select concat('john', ' (' + null + ')', ' adams') -- john adams
select concat('john', ' (test)', ' ' + null) -- john (test)
select concat('john', ' (the man)', ' adams') -- john (the man) adams
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  isnull(B.[SiloDesc], '') 
  + ' (' + isnull(B.[TitleDesc], '') + ') ' 
  + isnull(B.[SkillSetDesc], '') as SkillSetDesc,
```